# Finding the path to a pdf-viewer

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-viewer

I am only given the name of some `pdf-viewer`.

1) I want to check, if this `pdf-viewer` exists.

2) If this pdf-viewer exists, I want to find the path to it.

I am not sure how I have to approach.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: It's Linux. But does it depend on the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Linux, you can use terminal commands. If the PDF viewer has a command-line tool you could do something simple like so:

```
import subprocess
check = subprocess.check_output(['which', 'ls'])
print check
```

Otherwise, you could run an OS independent walk and search filenames like so:

```
import os

matches = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join('path', 'to', 'search'):
    for file in files:
        if 'pdf-viewer' in file.lower():
            filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
            matches.append(filepath)

print matches
```

This will walk all the directories starting at '/path/to/search' on Mac/Linux, or \path\to\search on PC. It will search all filenames within each directory for a match, ignoring case in this example. If a match is found, it will recreate the absolute path of the current directory and matched filename, and append it to your matches list. Then you can do what you want with the list of matches.

There's lots of info on how to use the os.Walk() function, but if you are on Python 2.7 I would recommend installing ScanDir, which is much faster (default for Python 3).

Comment: Does this provide me in case of the pdf-viewer a unique matching?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a unique matching. It will show any file on your system that matches the string "pdf-viewer". If you want to match exact file names you would change the line: `if 'pdf-viewer in file.lower():` to `if 'pdf-viewer' == file:`

Keep in mind that doing that will only match EXACT file names, so if the file has an extension such as .app or .exe, it will not return a result.